# want to have different border bottom size then background size

Tags: html, css

[What I am trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIJBI.png)

[What I now got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qx8L.png)

I want my background color to have a different size then my border bottom but I dont know how to do this.

```css
.underline {
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  border-bottom-color: red;
}

.background h3 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="background">
  <h3 class="underline">Hotels</h3>
</section>
```

Could someane help me? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for below solution. I think it's pretty self-explanatory.

#### Snippet

```css
.background {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.background h3 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="background">
  <h3 class="underline">Hotels</h3>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution above will work, but I advice not to use floats if possible:

```css
.title{
  color: white;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
 
}

.title-container{
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-container">
  <div class="title">Sports</div>
</div>
```